# Is there some equivalent to [ WHERE col IN (%) ] in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite query where I need the ability to get rows where a certain column (A, below) can either be anything (aka wildcard) or 1 of several options.

This works for wildcard or single values, but not multiple:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A LIKE "%"
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A LIKE "1"
```

This works for single or multiple values, but not wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A IN (1)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A IN (1, 2, 3)
```

What I would want to be able to do is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A IN (%)
```

I could use an if statement to choose between the first two options, except I actually have a lot of columns where I need to do this, more like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A IN (1, 2, 3) AND B IN (4, 5, 6) AND C IN (%) AND D IN (7, 8)
```

So nested "if" loops get pretty unwieldy.

So, is there a way to use a wildcard with WHERE IN or a way to have multiple possibilities in WHERE LIKE?

Answer (score 1):

If column is defined as `NOT NULL` you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A IN (A);
                          --for not nullable column it's equivalent of 1=1
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=e30b4f4b0ccdd91a9fa0d2e0840cb1c8)**

Comment: That's the ticket! I need an if statement for each column to set the query value to the name of the column, but this works.